# How to write this closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I want to create a method that processes a closure. The closure contains method calls and my closure method should execute them in order, e.g.:

```
when("I tap the Get Coffee button")
{
    _ in
        self.tap(p.button1)
        self.wait(1)
        self.tap(p.button1)
        return true
}
```

And my (simplified) closure method:

```
public func when(_ name:String, closure:(() -> Bool)? = nil)
{
    if let c = closure
    {
        _ = c()
    }
}
```

This results in error:

> cannot convert value of type '(_) -> _' to expected argument type '(()
>   -> Bool)?'

I don't understand what type needs to be defined in the closure argument for this to work.

Also, I'd like to eliminate the `self.` references in the closure, so that it works with:

```
when("I tap the Get Coffee button")
{
    _ in
        tap(p.button1)
        wait(1)
        tap(p.button1)
        return true
}
```

Comment: What's the point of making the closure optional? Would you ever call the `when` method with no closure?

Comment: And why define the closure with a return type of `Bool` if you are just doing to ignore the return value?

Comment: @maddy there are reasons for both of these, hence I wrote (simplified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `_ in`. That tells the compiler that the closure has a parameter but your closure is `() -> Bool`, that is, without parameters.

As for removing the `self`, you have to make the closure non-escaping. All optional closures are `@escaping`, therefore the closure would have to be non-optional:

```
public func when(_ name:String, closure:(() -> Bool)) {
    _ = closure()
}

when("I tap the Get Coffee button") {
    tap(p.button1)
    wait(1)
    tap(p.button1)
    return true
}
```

An escaping closure can create ownership cycles (memory leaks) and that's why every use of `self` (`self` would be captured) must be explicit.

Comment: Yes, I know but I still like to know to change it so that it uses the correct argument type for this code. Also, what about eliminating `.self`?

Comment: So it's the optionality? Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you want. I might be wrong though.

Since you want to use `tap` and `wait` without `self`, you need these in the closure's parameter list.

The signature of `tap` seems to be `(UIButton) -> ()` and the signature of `wait` seems to be `(Int) -> ()`.

So, pass these two closures to the closure.

Since the type is getting quite complicated, I suggest you use a type alias:

```
 typealias WhenHandler = ((UIButton) -> (), (Int) -> ()) -> Bool
```

And your `when` method can just be:

```
public func when(_ name:String, closure: WhenHandler)
```

You should pass `self.tap` and `self.wait` to the `closure` in the `when` method like this:

```
if let c = closure
{
    _ = c(self.tap, self.wait)
}
```

Now, you can call `when` like this:

```
when("I tap the Get Coffee button")
{
    tap, wait in
        tap(p.button1)
        wait(1)
        tap(p.button1)
        return true
}
```